# Problem with footer only first page docx4j

Tags: java, docx4j

Good morning 
I try to create a .docx documento using docx4j.
In the document I need to insert the footer only in the first page.
This is my code

```
private WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage;
private ObjectFactory factory;
private FooterPart footerPart;
private Ftr footer;

public void creaDocumentoConFooterImmagine() throws Exception {
    wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
    factory = Context.getWmlObjectFactory();
    Relationship relationship = this.createFooterPart();
    this.createFooterReference(relationship);
    
    wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText("Hello Word!");
     
    URL logo = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Footer.jpg");
    InputStream is = logo.openStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] byteChunk = new byte[4096]; // Or whatever size you want to read in at a time.
    int n;

    while ( (n = is.read(byteChunk)) > 0 ) {
        baos.write(byteChunk, 0, n);
    }       
    this.addImageInline(baos.toByteArray());    
    
    addPageBreak();

    wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addParagraphOfText("This is page 2!");
    
    File exportFile = new File("C:\\footerConImmagine.docx");
    wordMLPackage.save(exportFile);      
}

private void addImageInline(byte[] byteArray) throws Exception {
    BinaryPartAbstractImage imagePart = BinaryPartAbstractImage.createImagePart(wordMLPackage, footerPart, byteArray);
    int docPrId = 1;
    int cNvPrId = 2;
    Inline inLine = imagePart.createImageInline("Filename hint", "Alternative text", docPrId, cNvPrId, false);

    if (footer != null) {
        this.addInlineImageToFooter(inLine);
    }
}

private void addInlineImageToFooter(Inline inLine) {
   // Now add the in-line image to a paragraph
   ObjectFactory factory2 = new ObjectFactory();
   P paragraph2 = factory2.createP();
   R run = factory.createR();
   paragraph2.getContent().add(run);
   Drawing drawing = factory.createDrawing();
   run.getContent().add(drawing);
   drawing.getAnchorOrInline().add(inLine);
   footer.getContent().add(paragraph2); 
}

private void createFooterReference(Relationship relationship) {
   List<SectionWrapper> sections = wordMLPackage.getDocumentModel().getSections();

   SectPr sectionProperties = sections.get(sections.size() - 1).getSectPr();
   // There is always a section wrapper, but it might not contain a sectPr
   if (sectionProperties == null) {
      sectionProperties = factory.createSectPr();
      wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(sectionProperties);
      sections.get(0).setSectPr(sectionProperties);
   }
   
   FooterReference footerReference = factory.createFooterReference();
   footerReference.setId(relationship.getId());
   footerReference.setType(HdrFtrRef.FIRST);
   sectionProperties.getEGHdrFtrReferences().add(footerReference);
   
}

private Relationship createFooterPart() throws InvalidFormatException {
    footerPart = new FooterPart();
    footerPart.setPackage(wordMLPackage);
    footerPart.setJaxbElement(this.createFooter("Text"));
    return wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(footerPart);
}

//inserisco il testo del footer
private Ftr createFooter(String content) {
    footer = factory.createFtr();
    P paragraph = factory.createP();
    R run = factory.createR();
    Text text = new Text();
    text.setValue(content);
    run.getContent().add(text);
    paragraph.getContent().add(run);
    footer.getContent().add(paragraph);
    return footer;

}

/**
 * Adds a page break to the document.
 */
private void addPageBreak() {
    MainDocumentPart documentPart = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart();

    Br breakObj = new Br();
    breakObj.setType(STBrType.PAGE);

    P paragraph = factory.createP();
    paragraph.getContent().add(breakObj);
    documentPart.getJaxbElement().getBody().getContent().add(paragraph);
}
```

If I set

```
footerReference.setType(HdrFtrRef.DEFAULT);
```

the footer is created properly, so the code seems correct. 
I use this version of docx4j library: 6.1.2 
How can I debug the problem? 
Is there same example in the documentation of the library? 
Thanks 
Regards

Comment: I think you'll find the for a first page only footer, Word also creates the other footer as empty.  Try then deleting the other footer.  I suspect the first page only footer is then treated differently.

Comment: Thanks fo your  answer. What does it means "deleting the other footer"? In my code there is only one footer.

Comment: "delete the other footer" in a test docx created in Word, by unzipping it, removing the footer part, removing the rel pointing to it, and adjusting the sectPr element contents, then zip back up again.  Or do the same thing using docx4j.